# Convert a txt file into JSON

Tags: json, bash

I need to convert a simple txt list into a specific json format.

My list looks like this :

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
```

I need to have a JSON output that would look like this :

```
{ "data": [
 { "{SERVER}":"server1" },
 { "{SERVER}":"server2" },
 { "{SERVER}":"server3" },
 { "{SERVER}":"server4" }
]}
```

I was able to generate this with a bash script but I don't know how to remove the comma for the last line. The list is dynamic and can have a different amount of servers every time the script is run. 
Any tip please ?

EDIT : my current code :

```
echo "{ "data": [" > /tmp/json_output
for srv in `cat /tmp/list`; do
echo "{ \"{SERVER}\":\"$srv\" }," >> /tmp/json_output
done
echo "]}" >> /tmp/json_output
```

I'm very new at this, sorry if I sound noobish.

Comment: Show us your code and where it fails, thanks

Comment: Use a program like `jq` to generate the JSON from your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `jq` for this.

```
$ jq -nR 'reduce inputs as $i ([]; .+[$i]) | map ({"{SERVER}": .}) | {data: .}' tmp.txt
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server1"
    },
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server2"
    },
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server3"
    },
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server4"
    }
  ]
}
```

(It seems to me there should be an easier way to produce the array `["server1", "server2", "server3", "server4"]` to feed to the `map` filter, but this is functional.)

---

Breaking this down piece by piece, we first create an array of your server names.

```
$ jq -nR 'reduce inputs as $item ([]; .+[$item])' tmp.txt
[
  "server1",
  "server2",
  "server3",
  "server4"
]
```

This array is fed to a `map` filter that creates an array of objects with the `{SERVER}` key:

```
$ jq -nR 'reduce inputs as $item ([]; .+[$item]) | map ({"{SERVER}": .})' tmp.txt
[
  {
    "{SERVER}": "server1"
  },
  {
    "{SERVER}": "server2"
  },
  {
    "{SERVER}": "server3"
  },
  {
    "{SERVER}": "server4"
  }
]
```

And finally, this is used to create an object that maps the key `data` to the array of objects, as shown at the top.

Comment: The filter could be this: `{data:[{"{SERVER}":inputs}]}` (with `-Rn`)

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy for [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel -s input.txt -e '{"data":[x:lines($raw) ! {"{SERVER}":.}]}'
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server1"
    },
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server2"
    },
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server3"
    },
    {
      "{SERVER}": "server4"
    }
  ]
}
```

`x:lines($raw)` is a shorthand for `tokenize($raw,'\r\n?|\n')`. It creates an array of every new line.

In human terms you can see `x:lines($raw) ! {"{SERVER}":.}` as *"create a JSON object for every new line"*.

See also [this xidelcgi demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=server1%0Aserver2%0Aserver3%0Aserver4&=&extract=%7B%22data%22%3A%5Bx%3Alines(%24raw)%20!%20%7B%22%7BSERVER%7D%22%3A.%7D%5D%7D&=%7B%22data%22%3A%5Bx%3Alines(%24raw)%20!%20%7B%22%7BSERVER%7D%22%3A.%7D%5D%7D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).

Answer (score 0):

As others said a tool like `jq` should better be used.
Alternatively, you could use an array and determine whether the element you process is the last or not, for example your code could be :

```
declare -a servers
servers=($(cat /tmp/list))
pos=$(( ${#servers[*]} - 1 ))
last=${servers[$pos]}

echo "{ "data": [" > /tmp/json_output
for srv in "${servers[@]}"; do
if [[ $srv == $last ]]
then
        echo "{ \"{SERVER}\":\"$srv\" }" >> /tmp/json_output
else
        echo "{ \"{SERVER}\":\"$srv\" }," >> /tmp/json_output
fi
done
echo "]}" >> /tmp/json_output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Python 3 :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
import json

d = []
with open('listofservers.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for server in f:
        d.append({'{Server}' : server.rstrip("\n")})

print(json.dumps({'data': d}, indent=" "))
```

Which will print :

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "{Server}": "server1"
  },
  {
   "{Server}": "server2"
  },
  {
   "{Server}": "server3"
  },
  {
   "{Server}": "server4"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: @chepner Thanks!